# Highlight a cell Based on a range on cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, cells

I'm trying to highlight a cell based on the following conditions:

For example: 
I want to give the colour red to A1  cell if in a range between A2 until A30 at least one cell has colour blue. 
I already made it but only got red in A1 if all A2 to A30 are in blue, and not at least only one.

How can I achieve this?

If I'm not clear enough I can show in Excel what I made so far.

Answer (score 0):

*Your issue can be fixed using color identification &  helper values.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Either Press **Alt+F11** or **Right Click** the sheet TAB, to open VB editor.
- On top left find **P**roject Explorer windows.
- Select current **S**heet, then **R**ight click it, and select **I**nsert Module.
- Now **C**opy & **P**aste this code.

  ```
  Function IdentifyColor(CellToTest As Range)

   IdentifyColor = CellToTest.Interior.Color

  End Function
  ```
- Formula in cell `Y1`, and fill it down.

`=IdentifyColor(X1)`

- Formula in cell `Z1`:

`=COUNTIF($Y$1:$Y$10,"12611584")`

- Finally select required cell/cells & reach to Conditional Formatting, New Rule & use this Formula.

`=$Z1=1`

- Apply an appropriate cell format & finish with **O**k.

**N.B.**

- `12611584`is  color code of Blue.
- Shown method applies cell format on cell `X1`, if and when at least one cell in `X1:X10` has color `Blue`.
- You may adjust the New Rule formula as well as cell references as needed.
- For neatness later on you may hide Column `X` & `Y`.